# AJAX reload DIV

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to reload my div names shoutbox:

```
echo '<div id="shoutbox"><ul>';
    $results = $db->query($sql);
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<span class="date">'.date("d/m/Y H:i", strtotime($row['date_time'])).' </span>';
        echo '<span class="name">'.$row['name'].' - </span>';
        echo '<span class="message">'.$row['message'].'</span>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</div></ul>';
```

But i don't know how to do that with AJAX... sow the div has to reload when you klik the submit button and every 60 mili-seconds.

if someone can help me, it will be fine.

Comment: Every 60 millisecond is too much.

Comment: "and every 60 mili-seconds" This wouldn't be possible using ajax. It is but it's just calling for trouble. As i see it, you should use WebSockets instead or rethink about your logic

Comment: Yeah, 60 mili-seconds is verry less... every second maybe?

Comment: even every second can be dangerous. Use long-polling instead.

Comment: what do u recomand then?

Comment: ... long polling is what i recommend. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code

Comment: I would send via ajax for a .php then return an html with the data and just put the data inside the `shoutbox` by using .html(data)

Answer (score 0):

Michel is on the right track. You should get the data from php, and return json formatted data so that the client can update in javascript. Check out the jquery getJSON function: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/. Then you set that in a javascript "setInterval" function, like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
      var items = [];
      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
      });

      $( "#shoutbox ul", {
        html: items.join( "" )
      }).appendTo( "body" );
    });
}, 100);
```

This would reload the array of data every 100 miliseconds.

Comment: I guess you mean setInterval instead or better a timeout which be recalled once request has completed. But anyway calling an ajax request every 100ms is not a good practice

Comment: Thats a terrible idea. If the call takes more than 100ms to execute, calls will be issued in parallel until the browser goes boom. You can instead put a setTimeout in the success handler to call itself again - so it only launches a new request 100ms after the last one finished.